# Populate a ListView with GeoPoints near me

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, geopoints

I have a table at Parse.com full of addresses of places.

Every row contains the name of the address, and a GeoPoint (Latitude and Longitude).

I want to do 2 things:

1. Populate a ListView with data from my table (name and address), but places that are not further than, for example, 500 meters;

2. Convert the GeoPoint to an address (Street, City), so every ListView item will be shown like this:

Address Name

Street (with number of the house), City.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you have any latitude and longitude information for Near Places ?

Comment: Please share your DB structure and other things which will help us understand your situation better.

Comment: I've entered latitude and longitude into my GeoPoint column.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please help me! I need an answer until this afternoon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my first question. I've added that code in the activity AsyncTask on the doInBackground method.

Use [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial) guide, together with

```
query.whereWithinKilometers("Location", geoPoint, 1.5);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer